# Twitter OAuth Request_Token with Javascript, possibly wrong time?

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying and failing to get a token from twitter.
I get the following error: "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".
I have read it can be due to your system clock being wrong.
In javascript I tested my date with the following code

```
var minutes=1000*60;
var hours=minutes*60;
var days=hours*24;
var years=days*365;
var d=new Date();
var t=d.getTime();
var y=t/years;
console.log((y+1970) + " year and " + (t%years)/days)
```

This gave me the year as 2012 and 17 days..
1972
1976
1980
1984
1988
1992
1996
2000
2004
2008
*_*_=10 leap days. Today is the 8th, so taking away leap days it appears my system clock is on the 7th? Or have I made a mistake here? If this is the problem how do I fix correct my clock?

In cmd when I do the date cmd it gives me todays date, i.e the 8th.

Here is my post request and code in case the problem lies within the code and not the clock.

My Post request is:

```
POST http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=127.0.0.1&oauth_consumer_key=FFZJrBaPLsiwTDg5159tTQ&oauth_nonce=tWHEEIW8vLS6tMggo3IXe6e449qv1GpE8LunKRsbRF&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1326039495&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=d%2BQqgTzJCjYIp9vKwm%2BCWzVLPvA
```

which gets 401 (Unauthorized)

Here is my javascript code.

```
var url = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

var params={
oauth_callback : "127.0.0.1"
,oauth_consumer_key : "FFZJrBaPLsiwTDg5159tTQ"
,oauth_nonce : OAuth.nonce(42)
,oauth_signature_method : "HMAC-SHA1"
,oauth_timestamp : OAuth.timestamp()
,oauth_version: "1.0"}

//temp is to be the signature base string
var temp = toSignParams("POST",url,params); 
console.log(temp);
//This logs the signature base string as  "POST&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3D127.0.0.1%26oauth_consumer_key%3DFFZJrBaPLsiwTDg5159tTQ%26oauth_nonce%3D5gQVIa3WmwD6ARGGQTITl1Ozgxe2t8em5HC7g8wvMi%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1326038871%26oauth_version%3D1.0"
//which is correct I think.
//When I use this with the base signature from twitters oauth example page I get the result they got.
//it hashes the twitter signing key with base signature.
params.oauth_signature = b64_hmac_sha1("MCD8BKwGdgPHvAuvgvz4EQpqDAtx89grbuNMRd7Eh98&",temp);


var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST",toURIParams(url,params),true);  
req.send();

console.log(params)

req.onreadystatechange=function(){
if (req.readyState==4) 
    {
    console.log(req.responseText); //this is saying "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"
    }
}

//function to convert to Signature paramaters, as indicated on twitter page.
function toSignParams(method,base,params){
    tail=[];
    for (var p in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            tail.push(p + "%3D" + encodeURIComponent(params[p]));
        }
    }
    return method + "&" + encodeURIComponent(base) + "&" + tail.join("%26")
}

//function to convert to uri encoded parameters.
function toURIParams(base, params) {
  tail = [];
  for (var p in params) {
    if (params.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      tail.push(p + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[p]));
    }
  }
  return base + "?" + tail.join("&")
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've decided to use a javascript twitter library instead.

Comment: Post the JS library as an answer and accept the answer. That will help others when they come across your question.

Comment: "I have read it can be due to your system clock being wrong"... that just solved my problem after an hour of complete confusion as to why some OAuth code that worked last night was broken this morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a library called "jsOAuth-1.3.3" as was found on the twitter list of libraries compatible with JavaScript but is no longer there.

The 2 javascript options they list now are:

- user-stream by @AivisSilins — a simple Node.js User streams client
  and
- codebird-js by @mynetx — a Twitter Library in JScript.

as found on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

If anybody has a problem where they can't get either of those solutions to work, I can try find online or upload the library I used somewhere.